# How to set variable in power automate (escalation, timeout scenario)

Tags: power-automate

How can I set variable where are two approvals in flow?
First approval has timeout parametr and after timeout second approval start. How to set variable with two approval comments like:

if(first approval result null then set variable comments aprroval second) or if(first approval result is not null set variable comments first approval)

I try use union(body response first approval, body response second approval) in foreach but without success.

Something like this:

union(null,body response second approval) or union(body response first approval,null)

Comment: When you say `I try use union(body response first approval, body response second approval) in foreach but without success.`, what do you mean? do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, I get an error. One of the body response is null value because we have two different scenarios approval - always one is null. And I would like to be able to handle such a case with a variable.